# MySQL query adding a value to a new column

Tags: mysql

Trying to do a query but need to add 250 to TotalCost if mileage is > 150.

```
select milegae.dc_id, 
mileage.store_id, 
mileage.mileage, 
round((mileage.mileage * .75 + 200),2) as TripCost
from mileage;
```

This query gives me the data I want but I'm unsure how to add 250 to the TotalCost given the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
select milegae.dc_id, 
    mileage.store_id, 
    mileage.mileage, 
    CASE WHEN mileage.mileage > 150 
         THEN ROUND(((mileage.mileage+250) * .75 + 200),2) 
         ELSE ROUND((mileage.mileage * .75 + 200),2) 
    END as TripCost
from mileage;
```

Comment: dude, I think 250 should add after all calculations.

Comment: Maybe, not clear at all... The OP can do some of the work too :) @Ullas

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether the mileage > 150.

Hope you want to add `250` to the final value if the mileage value is greater than `150`.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  milegae.dc_id, 
  mileage.store_id, 
  mileage.mileage,
  CASE WHEN mileage.mileage > 150 
    THEN round((mileage.mileage * .75 + 200),2) + 250
    ELSE round((mileage.mileage * .75 + 200),2) 
  END AS TripCost
FROM mileage;
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I tried that but my Syntax was incorrect.  Your solution works perfectly!!!